# C#: Nat Traversal .Net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, nat

I'm currently trying to create a program using Nat Traversal,this has been supported in C# since .Net 4.0. Unfortunately, the client has to integrate with Unity, which is running .Net 3.5. The server operates outside Unity, so can use 4.0+ features.

All libraries that supported this feature have been left behind, as support was available in 2009.

Is there any way to connect the client and the server. I'm wondering if I can use the 4.0 traversal feature and directly connect from 3.5, but I cannot test this as I lack a remote host to execute from.

Note: I've been using this as a guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ncl/archive/2009/07/27/end-to-end-connectivity-with-nat-traversal-.aspx

Comment: If this is a client-server based game, why do you need NAT traversal? Can't you just forward a port on the server side? Or are the users meant to be able to make servers themselves?

Comment: Technically its a mod, which is why the server cannot use unity functions (the server is pure C#)

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still not sure I understand. Are you modding the server or the client, or both?

Comment: The game is a single player one (KSP for reference), and I'm trying to make it have better multiplayer support (I'm forking a pre-existing mod), but want to allow the creation of servers behind a Nat, and to not require port forwarding (for simplicity's sake)